# Javascript onclick variable not working

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why this is not working:

```
<a href="#" onclick="play('playlist1');">Play Playlist1</a>
function play(id){
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist(id);
}
```

And this is working:

```
<a href="#" onclick="play();">Play Playlist1</a>
function play(){
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist(playlist1);
}
```

There is also a variable called playlist1

```
var playlist1 = [
    {
        title:"Title",
        artist:"artist",
        mp3: "pathtofile"
    }];
```

So i need the first one to set the variable to get the right playlist.

It is the same value so it really weird,
 but i need the first one to work

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is playlist1 in this? Can you add a JS Fiddle with the above and playlist1 etc?

Comment: In your first example, `playlist1` is a string, in the second a variable.

Comment: Its a variable with the music in it. And i can;t do this in JS Fiddle because it needs alot of files

Comment: @Kevinkuijer, is it supposed to be that `var playlist` the input for the function `onclick="play('playlist1');"`? Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Since it is impossible for the examples paged to be the actual code  (missing script node), can you post examples of the actual code being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first, non-working example, you are passing `'playlist1'` as a string, rather than the `playlist1` variable. Simply removing the single quotes should be enough to fix it.

**Example:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="play(playlist1);">Play Playlist1</a>
function play(id){
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist(id);
}
```

Another solution would be to look up the variable by the string name via `window[id]`.

**Example:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="play('playlist1');">Play Playlist1</a>
function play(id){
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist(window[id]);
}
```